# Script Does not Work When Called From Another Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script named `backup_dotfile` (in `$PATH`) like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "\nDo you want to backup dotfiles?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* )
            read -p "Please Enter Commit Message: " Commit_Message;
            git --git-dir=/media/blueray/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup --work-tree="$HOME" add -A;
            git --git-dir=/media/blueray/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup --work-tree="$HOME" commit -am "$Commit_Message";
            break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done
```

It saves my dotfiles in a bare repo.

If I call this script independently then it works.

However, I have another script named `backup` (in `$PATH`).

Which looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf $'\033[31m\nBacking Up dotfiles\033[0m\n';

backup-dotfiles;
```

when I invoke `backup`, there is not log entry in `git --git-dir=/media/blueray/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup --work-tree="$HOME" log`

So, `backup` does not call `backup_dotfile` properly.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: From where do you call your `backup` script? From the command line? Are there changes to commit when you run `backup`?

Comment: The `backup` script is in the `$PATH`. So I can call it from terminal. As it is a bare repo, I call the script from any place. Not in the bare repo directory. The path is defined using `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`. And it works when I use `backup_dotfile`. After you mentioned, I noticed when "there are changes to commit", **it works**.

Comment: So the script works as expected then? When there are no changes to be committed, no changes _are_ committed. Whet there are changes to commit, these are committed.  Right?

Comment: you said your first script is called `backup_dotfiles` (with an underscore), but your second script is called `backup-dotfiles` (with a dash).  Is that a typo in just your question here, or in your 2nd script?   BTW, you don't need a single `;` after every command in a case statement (unless the're more than one command on a line), you only need `;;` at the end of each case.

Comment: you can also make the script a bit more readable by using a variable for the backup dir - e.g. `dfbackup='/media/blueray/WDRed/_Working/_dotfiles-backup'` and, later, use `--git-dir="$dfbackup"`.  any data you use more than once in a script is a good candidate for putting in a variable, especially if it's a long string.